# Unity error when using rigidbody.MovePosition

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to create a planet game in Unity 2017.03.1f1, and am following [this
tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TicipSVT-T) to make the planet's gravity. Whenever I try to enter this line of code(Around the 20 minute mark):

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    rigidbody.MovePosition(rigidbody.position + transform.TransformDirection(moveAmount) * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
}
```

I can't manage to get the line to work, and Unity gives me this text:

> "Assets/Scripts/FirstPersonController.cs(36,19): error CS1061: Type `UnityEngine.Component` does not contain a definition for `MovePosition` and no extension method `MovePosition` of type `UnityEngine.Component` could be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?"

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1):

The `rigidbody` variable which is declared as a `Component` has been deprecated long time ago. You are now required to use the `GetComponent` function to get the `Rigidbody` component that is attached to this GameObject. After making the fix to `rigidbody.MovePosition`, also do the-same where you used `rigidbody.position`.

This is the what the updated code should look like:

```
Rigidbody rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
rb.MovePosition(rb.position + transform.TransformDirection(moveAmount) * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
```